# ASP.NET MVC to call my Dependency Resolver when creating an instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC so I hope my question makes sense. I'm using POCO objects as my model. It's my understanding that when the form is submitted MVC can create a new instance of my business object and fill the properties from the form automatically.

I use dependency injection so I create new instances using code like the following:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.CreateInstance(Of IBusObject)
```

How can I get ASP.NET MVC to call this method instead of trying to create a new instance by using the "new" keyword on the concrete class?

Comment: BTW, you might want to look at using lightweight view models for sending to your views and receiving information back. This makes for cleaner binding and allows you to apply validation attributes which are UI concerns. These view models should not involve any DI so would remove your need to create a custom model binder. You can map from your POCO classes to view models using AutoMapper

Comment: @Rob I just changed my business objects to implement IDataErrorInfo to pass the validation errors up. If I use view models, do you know if I need to move the IDataErrorInfo implementation up to the view model?

Comment: If you adopt the view model approach then I think that is the natural place to put validation. The MVC framework will use this to drive binding behaviour in the model binder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the MVC source code it will not use dependency resolution when creating an instance of the model type, so you can't get what you want out of the box, but you could easily achieve what you want by creating your own model binder which is DependencyResolver aware.

Comment: Where should I save the custom model binder?

Comment: Model binding is a UI concern so I store mine in the web application project. I create a specific folder in the project for model binders.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom model binder deriving from the default model binder and override the [CreateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.createmodel.aspx) method to supply your custom instance.

Comment: Where should I save the custom model binder?

Comment: @adam0101, what do you mean by *save the custom model binder*? It's a class that is normally defined in the web tier.

Comment: I mean where should the file live. Would it go in the Models folder that MVC creates? Or does it not matter?